# Unreal GAS: Print out the current value of an attribute to UI when it changes

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-gameplay-ability-system

When the base value of an attribute changes, there is `UAttributeSet::PostGameplayEffectExecute()` available to access the (new) value and *GameplayEffect* with its context. I'm using this to print the changed value to UI (this is also done in ActionRPG).

Is there something similar available for the **current value** of an attribute? How to notify UI, when `FGameplayAttributeData::CurrentValue` is updated?

---

- Though `UAttributeSet::PreAttributeChange()` is called on every value update, it doesn't provide any context so it is not possible to access the UI from there (events broadcasted by `FAggregator` also don't fit).
- It is possible to use a *GameplayCue* instead, to set the value of `FGameplayAttributeData::CurrentValue` within the UI (the cue is triggered by the *GameplayEffect* who sets the current value). This is possible by deriving from a `GameplayCueNotifyActor` and use its events `OnExecute` and `OnRemove`. However, instantiating an actor just to update UI seems to be a waste of resources.
- It is also possible to fetch the information using the UI itself (calling a function which accesses the attribute each tick or with a timer), but in comparison to event driven UI update, this is also wasteful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GameplayAbilitySystem has `UAbilitySystemComponent::GetGameplayAttributeValueChangeDelegate()` which returns a callback of type `FOnGameplayAttributeValueChange` that is triggered whenever an attribute is changed (base value or current value). This can be used to register a delegate/callback, which can be used to update the UI.

#### Minimal example

In `MyCharacter.h`

```
// Declare the type for the UI callback.
DECLARE_DYNAMIC_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_OneParam(FAttributeChange, float, AttributeValue);

UCLASS()
class MYPROJECT_API MyCharacter : public ACharacter, public IAbilitySystemInterface
{
    // ...

    // This callback can be used by the UI.
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintAssignable, Category = "Attribute callbacks")
    FAttributeChange OnManaChange;

    // The callback to be registered within AbilitySystem.
    void OnManaUpdated(const FOnAttributeChangeData& Data);

    // Within here, the callback is registered.
    void BeginPlay() override;

    // ...
}
```

In `MyCharacter.cpp`

```
void MyCharacter::OnManaUpdated(const FOnAttributeChangeData& Data)
{
    // Fire the callback. Data contains more than NewValue, in case it is needed.
    OnManaChange.Broadcast(Data.NewValue);
}

void MyCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    if (AbilitySystemComponent)
    {
        AbilitySystemComponent->GetGameplayAttributeValueChangeDelegate(MyAttributeSet::GetManaAttribute()).AddUObject(this, &MyCharacterBase::OnManaUpdated);
    }
}
```

In `MyAttributeSet.h`

```
UCLASS()
class MYPROJECT_API MyAttributeSet : public UAttributeSet
{
    // ...
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Mana", ReplicatedUsing=OnRep_Mana)
    FGameplayAttributeData Mana;

    // Add GetManaAttribute().
    GAMEPLAYATTRIBUTE_PROPERTY_GETTER(URPGAttributeSet, Mana)

    // ...
}
```

Example for updating the UI via the EventGraph of the character blueprint, which derived from `MyCharacter`. `UpdatedManaInUI` is the function which prints the value to the UI.

[image: Update attribute within blueprint]

Here, `UpdatedManaInUI` retrieves the value by itself. You might want to use the `AttributeValue` of `OnManaChange`.